# числа после URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

Здравствуйте.

Яндекс индексирует url страниц,  добавляя какие то цифры.
Пример:

***www.domen.ru/.../.../?52:26:0010015:998***

что это за цифры и как htaccess-ом перенаправить такие страницы на 404 страницу.

Сайт написан на wordpress

Заранее спасибо!!!

Comment: А почему только такие запросы должны 404 ошибку отдавать? Роутер вашего сайта должен все несуществующие страницы возвращать с кодом 404 по умолчанию.

Comment: все несуществующие он отправляет, но эти открывает страницы. например "www.domen.ru/.../name/52:26:0010015:998" открывает содержимое "www.domen.ru/.../name" этой страницы

Comment: Вы сами себе противоречите этим комментарием. Нужно роутер править, а не писать костыли в .htaccess.

Comment: можете подсказать как мне это надо сделать? сайт на wordpress

Comment: С `wordpress` не знаком. Добавьте этот тег в свой вопрос, возможно тогда знающие люди обратят на него внимание.

Comment: "www.domen.ru/.../name/52:26:0010015:998" таких страниц нету у сайта, но яндекс индексирует и при наборе в url оно открывается. Не пойму откуда они берутся - эти числа.

Comment: Где это можно увидеть в реальности?

Comment: вы знак вопроса куда дели из вопроса? У вас там не цифры, а обычный query - /?52: ....

Comment: сори, добавил ? знак. Но что это за query?

Comment: У меня по этому запросу отдал 403 ошибку

Comment: Эти цифры - кадастровый номер с вашего же сайта.

Comment: 403, я сейчас работаю над сайтом, htaccess-ом перенаправляю.

Comment: Боюсь я, что htaccess для Вордпресса тут не поможет. Получается, что вы боретесь с движком.

Comment: а как исправить, есть какие не будь предложения, готов послушать .

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57831/discussion-between-taron-and-labris).

Answer (score 0):

Все, что после знака вопроса - т.н. query, запрос к сайту. Как только вы перенаправите такие url на 404, сайт можно закрывать, потому что вы просто угробите его функционал.

Comment: а что делать, как решить?

Comment: Зачем вам вот это?

Comment: нет смысла индексировать такие страницы

Comment: Вы переживаете, что Яндекс перегреется? )